# Invoking another component in lightning salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, create-component

In my lightning component, calling a method on onclick event and in turn which calls an another component. which works fine  **but whenever the page is refreshed it fails to call the component *on First Click*** but works fine on second onClick

```
<ul aria-describedby="option-drag-label" aria-labelledby="label-46" aria-multiselectable="true" role="listbox" tabindex="0">
              <ui:inputSelect multiple="true" value="{!v.removeSelectedValues}" aura:id="rightSelectedValues" class="oSelect" click="{!c.getFieldDataType }" />
          </ul>
```

Onclick in the lightning component  calls the below method

```
    getFieldDataType : fucntion(component, event, helper){
       var mffldName = component.get("v.mffldName");
                  this.showFieldPropertySet(component, mffldName);
},
```

And after the response,a method in which the component is created.

```
showFieldPropertySet : function(component, mffldName){
        debugger;
        var mfId=component.get("v.mfId");
        var mffType = component.get("v.mffType");
        var ObjectName= component.get("v.mfObjName");

        $A.createComponent(   
            "c:CMP_FieldProperties",{  
                'mfId':mfId,       
                'mffType': mffType, 
                'mfObjName':ObjectName,
                'selOption': mffldName   
            },
            function(newComponent){
                component.set("v.body",newComponent); 
            });   
    },
```

Comment: A click is not the same as a page refresh, additionally, you are not sharing how you are calling your method. Please update your post

Comment: Try clearing v.body after creating the component but before setting it.

Comment: @glls yeah sure I will update the post :) sorry I didn't convey properly the thing is after page refresh it fails to call the component on First Click , but works like charm on secind click

Comment: have you declared aura:dependency in your cmp file, that generally improve performance for dynamically created component.

Answer (score 1):

> instead of using ui:select use lightning:select

```
<lightning:select name="colorId" label="Select a color:" aura:id="colorId" value="{!v.selectedValue}" onchange="{!c.getFieldDataType}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="option">
        <option text="{!option.label}" value="{!option.id}" selected="{!option.selected}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```